# Ограничение смещения блока, используя transform translate, mousemove и pageX (pageY)

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, mousemove

Я изменяю размеры и положения блока используя событие `mousemove`. Т.е. я изменяю `transform translate` и `width (height)` с помощью `pageX (pageY)`. Но из-за того, что событие мыши `mousemove` не успевает всегда отрабатывать (например, если быстро перемещать мышь) или не успевает считывать условия, блок выходит за границы.

Вопрос: что мне в этом случае нужно сделать, чтобы блок не выходил за границы?

Вот как примерно это выглядит:

```js
"use strict";
let second_block = document.getElementById('second_block');
let point = document.getElementById('point');

function change_second_block() {
  if (second_block.clientWidth < 500) {
    second_block.style.width = `${start_x + event.pageX}px`;
  }
}
point.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  window.start_x = second_block.clientWidth - event.pageX;
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', change_second_block);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.first_block {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
}

div#auxiliary_block {
  position: absolute;
}

div.second_block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
}

input.point {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  right: -7px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_block" class="first_block">
  <div id="auxiliary_block">
    <div id="second_block" class="second_block"></div>
    <input id="point" class="point" name="name_point" type="button">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="1.block_in_center_question.js"></script>
```

Т.е. в этом примере блок `.second_block` выходит за границы `first_block` (500px), т.е. условие он не успевает считывать. С помощью чего нужно решить данный вопрос?

Также для удобства https://jsfiddle.net/ManuOP/t1r4szdx/3/

Comment: для начала, добавьте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: @Макск тут и без кода понятен вопрос, разве нет?! А код писать слишком много, да и смысла нет особого. Если вам что-то не понятно в вопросе, так вы напишите, а я отвечу более подробно

Comment: @Manu комментарии не предназначены для подробного обсуждения. Как задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Макск я добавил код, есть соображение по существу вопроса?

Comment: @Rudi я добавил подробности, есть мысли по заданному вопросу?

Comment: @Manu ну если предложить хот-фикс, то вы можете в функцию "change_second_block" добавить ещё одну проверку, такого типа ```  else if (second_block.clientWidth >500) {

second_block.style.width = `500px`
  }```

Comment: @Макск этот вариант я уже рассматривал, но хочется увидеть решение более правильное, а именно, чтобы у блока даже возможности не было выйти за пределы

Comment: Ну тогда вариант ответа ниже, решает проблем выхода блока за границу с правой стороны :) .

Comment: @Макск Можете пояснить, почему в варианте Rudi он даже не выходит за пределы? А если использовать условие типа else if (second_block.clientWidth >500) { second_block.style.width = 500px} (точнее если добавить это условие в мой вариант), то при изменении он выйдет за пределы, но потом установит значение 500. Но дело в том, что он все равно на какой-то момент выйдет, а в варианте Rudi он даже не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так..

```js
"use strict";
let second_block = document.getElementById('second_block');
let point = document.getElementById('point');
let first_block = document.getElementById('first_block');
let mouseDown = false;

function change_second_block() {
  if(mouseDown && event.pageX < first_block.clientWidth){
    second_block.style.width = event.pageX + 'px';
  }
  if(mouseDown && event.pageX > first_block.clientWidth){
    second_block.style.width = first_block.clientWidth + 'px';
  }
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', change_second_block);
point.onmousedown = function(event) { mouseDown = true; }
document.onmouseup = function(event) { mouseDown = false; }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div.first_block {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
}
div#auxiliary_block {
    position: absolute;
}
div.second_block {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: orange;
}
input.point {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    border: none;
    background: black;
    right: -7px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_block" class="first_block">
    <div id="auxiliary_block"> 
        <div id="second_block" class="second_block"></div>
        <input id="point" class="point" name="name_point" type="button">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="1.block_in_center_question.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это похоже на то что я искал. Можете пояснить, почему в Вашем варианте он даже не выходит за пределы? А если использовать условие типа else if (second_block.clientWidth >500) { second_block.style.width = 500px} (точнее если добавить это условие в мой вариант), то при изменении он выйдет за пределы, но потом установит значение 500. Но дело в том, что он все равно на какой-то момент выйдет, а в Вашем варианте он даже не выходит

Comment: @Manu Потому, что сначала проверяется `if (second_block.clientWidth >500)` , в момент когда курсор уже рядом с краем, затем устанавливается ширина  `start_x + event.pageX` здесь прибавляется стартовое значение к текущему значению курсора по оси Х соответственно ширина блока больше..  Ещё `mousemove` навешивается на каждом клике, не надо его вкладывать в `mousedown`.

Comment: Спасибо. А если сделать триггер на mousemove, т.е. при mousedown на нужной кнопке триггер переключается и считывается событие mousemove - это не лучше будет постоянного прослушивания события mousemove? Я имею в виду загруженности сайта (сервера)

Comment: т.е. как сильно влияет постоянное прослушивание события mousemove на загруженность сайта, если много пользователей?

Comment: Можно удалять слушатель при mouseup [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Выполняется всё на клиенте грузится комп пользователя, сильно - не сильно, зависит от того, что делается с данными.. Комментарии не предназначены для подробного обсуждения. Лучше сформулировать и задать следующий вопрос..

Comment: Большое человеческое Спасибо тебе!

Comment: На здоровье! :)